# Android divider layout positioning

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to create a divider under the title in my android layout. I've read [this tutorial](http://sonnygill.net/android/horizontal-rule/) for create the blue one in the image below, but i want put it under the main title ("test")

### [image: Layout]

this is a part of the xml that concerning this layout part

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/WordContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/txtParola"
                  android:textColor="#33b5e5"
                  android:clickable="false"
                  android:linksClickable="false"
                  android:focusable="false"
                  android:text="test"
                  android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:editable="false" android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                  android:paddingTop="20dp" android:shadowColor="#000000" android:singleLine="true"
                  android:textSize="24pt"/>
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip">
             <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:background="#33b5e5" />
            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to have another nested `RelativeLayout`.  Instead, do:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/WordContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/txtParola"
                  android:textColor="#33b5e5"
                  android:clickable="false"
                  android:linksClickable="false"
                  android:focusable="false"
                  android:text="test"
                  android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:editable="false" android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                  android:paddingTop="20dp" android:shadowColor="#000000" android:singleLine="true"
                  android:textSize="24pt"/>
         <View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtParola"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txtParola"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/txtParola" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

With this, you are putting the line below the TextView, and then aligning the left and right edges to the TextView so that it stretches to the correct size.